# Запятая после деепричастного оборота с "который"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Из Google Books:

> Этим самым мы можем сформулировать целый каскад задач, решив **которые мы** можем разрешить исходное противоречие.
>
> Тем не менее есть вопросы, не решив **которые, мы** не сумеем придать работе парламента истинно демократический облик.
>
> Эта тема имеет множество ответвлений, исследовав **которые, мы** сможем пролить свет на то, как в действительности функционировало это общество.
>
> Некоторые мыслители даже пытались выделить некие абсолютные для всех времен и народов закономерности, понимая **которые мы** можем постичь и логику истории.

Ссылки на запросы: [[1]](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%22), [[2]](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%22), [[3]](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D1%8B%22).

---

Почему иногда запятая ставится, а иногда – нет? Нужна ли она?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не нужна.

Розенталь:

> 4) если деепричастие имеет в качестве зависимого слова союзное слово
>   который в составе определительной придаточной части сложноподчиненного
>   предложения (такое деепричастие от придаточной части запятой не
>   отделяется): *Перед старыми заводами возникали десятки серьёзных
>   проблем, **не решив которые** невозможно было перейти к новым методам
>   постройки кораблей (Коч.)*; *Направо была дверь, пройдя которую можно
>   было попасть в коридор, ведущий на сцену*; *Опубликованы новые
>   произведения молодого писателя, читая которые нетрудно видеть его
>   творческий рост*.

Лопатин:

> 4) если деепричастие в составе определительной придаточной части имеет
>   в качестве зависимого слова союзное слово который: *Перед нами стоит
>   задана, **не решив которую** мы не можем двигаться дальше*.

Если полагаться на правила, то можно уверенно сказать, что в двух предложениях ошибка.